# MySQL Database Schema Design - Tree-Style

Tags: mysql, database

I've almost never done a database design, so I really don't know how I could do this:

I need a structure, kind of a tree, which looks like:

```
-Main Item 1
--Sub Item 1
---SubSub Item 1
---SubSub Item 2
--Sub Item 2
---SubSub Item 1
-Main Item 2
.....

and so on.
```

The goal is to nest as many layers as I want for any item.

How can I create my database tables, so I can save this the best way. And how would a query look like to get this structure?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `table menu (id, name, parent_id, whatever, else, you, need)`

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/